Debian ca-certificates package contains expired trust certificates
Today on Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) install ca-certificates package and checked the /etc/ssl/certs directory .pem files, noticed some of the certificate expired.
These certificates expired in 2023,but this package still has these certs. What is the right way to clean up these expired certificates?
Not After : Mar  3 12:09:48 2023 GMT
./E-Tugra_Certification_Authority.pem


            Not After : May 15 04:52:29 2023 GMT
./Hongkong_Post_Root_CA_1.pem


            Not After : Sep 30 04:20:49 2023 GMT
./Security_Communication_Root_CA.pem

Thanks

File a bug to Debian, so the problem will be solved for all users.

@GiacomoCatenazzi I see this bug report https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1063093, looks like they are depending on Mozilla to clean-up.

You can manually delete the certificates and then perform an update.
Check and use the right path.
Example:
sudo rm PATH/E-Tugra_Certification_Authority.pem

Than update:
sudo update-ca-certificates

Maybe it is not necessary, but you can reboot the system too.
Sources:
How does one remove a certificate authority's certificate from a system?
How do you add a certificate authority (CA) to Ubuntu?
Removing certificate and re-running update-ca-certificates leaves lingering symlinks
How to remove a root CA certificate?

Bear in mind that certificates deleted in this manner won’t be restored the next time the package is upgraded.
